# mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): error

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

hi i've been using php for a while now but i'm still quiet new to a few things one of which is the bind_result(). So i'm creating a login system on a project but i keep getting the error:

mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

i know this is to do with the fact that i'm selecting all the columns, what i want to know do i have to bind all of the columns or is their an easier way?

my code in function.php

```
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?"; // SQL Statement
       $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql); // Prepare the SQL Statement
       $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // Bind the placeholder with the correct data type from the SQL Statement
       $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared statement
       $stmt->store_result(); // Store the prepared statement for later checking

       // Check to make sure if any data is returned
       if($stmt->num_rows) {

           // Create and append variables
           $user = $stmt->bind_result($email);


          // Create a while loop
           while($stmt->fetch()) {
              // verifying user password
              $salt = $user['salt'];
              $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
              $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
              // check for password equality
              if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                 // user authentication details are correct
                 $stmt->close();
                 return $user;
              }else {

            }
        }
            return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try selecting only the column you need. Selecting all columns does matter in regards to how many columns there are in contrast with the binded results. If you have more, than you'll need to add those to binding the results.

Comment: **WARNING**: Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead of whatever `checkhashSSHA` is as it looks in no way secure.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code. But as your query is not clear please encrypt your password and then check in if condition

```
function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email) {
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT
email,
password
FROM users
WHERE email = ?
');
$stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $row = array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password);
}
$stmt->close();
if(!empty($row)){
    return $row;
} else {
    return "";
}
```

}

```
 $userDetails = getUserByEmailAndPassword($email);
 //Encrypt your password here
 if($userDetails['password'] == $encryped_password){
  //do_something
 }
```